# How to implement multiple subcommands with Yargs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, yargs

I've been trying and trying, but just couldn't digest Yargs' [docs](http://yargs.js.org/docs/).

I need to create a set of commands/subcommands:

```
~$framework generate routed-module ModuleOne ModuleTwo ModuleThree --animation-style=bounce-up

//would call a handler with:
{ modules: string[], options: {animationStyle?: AnimationStyle}}
type AnimationStyle = 'bounce-up' | 'slide-left'
```

or

```
~$framework generate stateful-ui ModuleOne ModuleTwo ModuleThree
//would call a handler with:
{ modules: string[]}
```

or

```
~$framework init
//would just call a handler
```

I'd like aliases: 
`g` for `generate`,
`r` for `routed-module`,
`s` for `stateful-ui`.

Autocompletion would be nice.

Here's what I've tried, don't know where to go from here:

```
  yargs
    .scriptName('elm-framework')
    .command({
      command: 'generate [moduleType] [moduleNames]',
      aliases: ['g'],
      describe: 'Generates a resource',
      handler: config.handleModuleGeneration,
      builder: {
        moduleType: {
          demand: true,
          choices: ['routed', 'stateful'] as const,
          default: 'routed',
        },
        moduleNames: {
          demand: true,
          array: true,
        },
      },
    })
```

Thanx!

(Doing this with typescript is not necessary. I primarily want to understand how to use the library's api.)

Comment: have look at https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/examples.md

Answer (score 4):

To me, the best way to achieve this was following [this](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/225) Github issue, specifically what suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/225#issuecomment-699540088). (another `builder` nested inside the command `builder`).

The issue with using the suggestion above (`'generate [moduleType] [moduleNames...]'`) is that you can't use different flags for different sub-commands.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out using [this crucial piece of documentation](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#variadic-positional-arguments):

```
  yargs
    .scriptName('framework')
    .command({
      command: 'generate [moduleType] [moduleNames...]',
      aliases: ['g'],
      describe: 'Generates a resource',
      handler: parsed => console.log('your handler goes here', parsed),
      builder: {
        moduleType: {
          demand: true,
          choices: ['routed', 'stateful'] as const,
          default: 'routed',
        },
        moduleNames: {
          demand: true,
          array: true,
        },
      },
    }).parse(process.argv.slice(2))
```